# how to get the full path of the process executable file based on ebpf？

Tags: ebpf

how to get the full path of the process executable file by struct task base on ebpf？ I want to get the full path of the process executable file by struct task base on ebpf,now i can get the ptgid from the task, the code such as:

```
int get_ptgid(struct task_struct *task) {
     u32 ptgid; 
     struct task_struct *parent;
     bpf_probe_read(&parent, sizeof(parent), &task->real_parent);
     bpf_probe_read(&ptgid, sizeof(ptgid), &parent->tgid);
     return ptgid;
}
```

but i don not know how to get the full path of the process executable file by struct task,who can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

An example of getting the full path from **struct path** can be seen in projects [Tracee](https://github.com/aquasecurity/tracee/blob/a6118678c6908c74d6ee26ca9183e99932d098c9/pkg/ebpf/c/common/filesystem.h#L160) or [Tetragon](https://github.com/cilium/tetragon/blob/bdebfece967a3ff4dbd3693b4d7caaee0e2f1a1a/bpf/process/bpf_process_event.h#L236). To simplify:

```
#define EFAULT 14 /* Bad address */

#define MAX_PATH_SIZE 4096 // PATH_MAX from <linux/limits.h>
#define LIMIT_PATH_SIZE(x) ((x) & (MAX_PATH_SIZE - 1))
#define MAX_PATH_COMPONENTS 20

statfunc long get_path_str_from_path(u_char **path_str, struct path *path, struct buffer *out_buf) {

  long ret;
  struct dentry *dentry, *dentry_parent, *dentry_mnt;
  struct vfsmount *vfsmnt;
  struct mount *mnt, *mnt_parent;
  const u_char *name;
  size_t name_len;

  dentry = BPF_CORE_READ(path, dentry);
  vfsmnt = BPF_CORE_READ(path, mnt);
  mnt = container_of(vfsmnt, struct mount, mnt);
  mnt_parent = BPF_CORE_READ(mnt, mnt_parent);

  size_t buf_off = HALF_PERCPU_ARRAY_SIZE;

#pragma unroll
  for (int i = 0; i < MAX_PATH_COMPONENTS; i++) {

    dentry_mnt = BPF_CORE_READ(vfsmnt, mnt_root);
    dentry_parent = BPF_CORE_READ(dentry, d_parent);

    if (dentry == dentry_mnt || dentry == dentry_parent) {
      if (dentry != dentry_mnt) {
        // We reached root, but not mount root - escaped?
        break;
      }
      if (mnt != mnt_parent) {
        // We reached root, but not global root - continue with mount point path
        dentry = BPF_CORE_READ(mnt, mnt_mountpoint);
        mnt_parent = BPF_CORE_READ(mnt, mnt_parent);
        vfsmnt = __builtin_preserve_access_index(&mnt->mnt);
        continue;
      }
      // Global root - path fully parsed
      break;
    }

    // Add this dentry name to path
    name_len = LIMIT_PATH_SIZE(BPF_CORE_READ(dentry, d_name.len));
    name = BPF_CORE_READ(dentry, d_name.name);

    name_len = name_len + 1; // add slash
    // Is string buffer big enough for dentry name?
    if (name_len > buf_off) { break; }
    volatile size_t new_buff_offset = buf_off - name_len; // satisfy verifier
    ret = bpf_probe_read_kernel_str(
      &(out_buf->data[LIMIT_HALF_PERCPU_ARRAY_SIZE(new_buff_offset) // satisfy verifier
    ]),
      name_len,
      name);
    if (ret < 0) { return ret; }

    if (ret > 1) {
      buf_off -= 1;                                    // remove null byte termination with slash sign
      buf_off = LIMIT_HALF_PERCPU_ARRAY_SIZE(buf_off); // satisfy verifier
      out_buf->data[buf_off] = '/';
      buf_off -= ret - 1;
      buf_off = LIMIT_HALF_PERCPU_ARRAY_SIZE(buf_off); // satisfy verifier
    } else {
      // If sz is 0 or 1 we have an error (path can't be null nor an empty string)
      break;
    }
    dentry = dentry_parent;
  }

  // Is string buffer big enough for slash?
  if (buf_off != 0) {
    // Add leading slash
    buf_off -= 1;
    buf_off = LIMIT_HALF_PERCPU_ARRAY_SIZE(buf_off); // satisfy verifier
    out_buf->data[buf_off] = '/';
  }

  // Null terminate the path string
  out_buf->data[HALF_PERCPU_ARRAY_SIZE - 1] = 0;
  *path_str = &out_buf->data[buf_off];
  return HALF_PERCPU_ARRAY_SIZE - buf_off - 1;
}
```

For example, you can get a structure from a structure like this:

```
struct task_struct *task = (struct task_struct *)bpf_get_current_task();
struct file *file = BPF_CORE_READ(task, mm, exe_file);
struct path *path = __builtin_preserve_access_index(&file->f_path);
```

You also need to get a buffer of sufficient size for a path. For example like this:

```
#define MAX_PERCPU_ARRAY_SIZE (1 << 15)
#define HALF_PERCPU_ARRAY_SIZE (MAX_PERCPU_ARRAY_SIZE >> 1)
#define LIMIT_PERCPU_ARRAY_SIZE(x) ((x) & (MAX_PERCPU_ARRAY_SIZE - 1))
#define LIMIT_HALF_PERCPU_ARRAY_SIZE(x) ((x) & (HALF_PERCPU_ARRAY_SIZE - 1))

struct buffer {
  u8 data[MAX_PERCPU_ARRAY_SIZE];
};

struct {
  __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_PERCPU_ARRAY);
  __type(key, u32);
  __type(value, struct buffer);
  __uint(max_entries, 1);
} heaps_map SEC(".maps");

statfunc struct buffer *get_buffer() {
  u32 zero = 0;
  return (struct buffer *)bpf_map_lookup_elem(&heaps_map, &zero);
}
```

Final:

```
#include "vmlinux.h"

#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_core_read.h>

#define statfunc static __attribute__((__always_inline__))

...

char LICENSE[] SEC("license") = "GPL";

// trace/events/sched.h: TP_PROTO(struct task_struct *p, pid_t old_pid, struct linux_binprm *bprm)
SEC("raw_tracepoint/sched_process_exec")
int raw_tracepoint_sched_process_exec(struct bpf_raw_tracepoint_args *ctx) {
    struct task_struct *task = (struct task_struct *)bpf_get_current_task();
    // or struct task_struct *task = (struct task_struct *)ctx->args[0];
    struct file *file = BPF_CORE_READ(task, mm, exe_file);
    /* or
      struct linux_binprm *bprm = (struct linux_binprm *)ctx->args[2];
      struct file *file = BPF_CORE_READ(bprm, file);
    */
    struct path *path = __builtin_preserve_access_index(&file->f_path);

  struct buffer *string_buf = get_buffer();
  if (string_buf == NULL) { return 0; }
  u_char *file_path = NULL;
  get_path_str_from_path(&file_path, path, string_buf);

  bpf_printk("--> %s\n", file_path);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To get the full path from the task_struct, you need to call the kernel function d_path
https://archive.kernel.org/oldlinux/htmldocs/filesystems/API-d-path.html
Pass
task->mm->exe_file->f_path as the first parameter
char * d_path(f_path, buf, buflen);
There is a bpf_d_path function in libbpf, but for some reason it does not work for my type of tracepoint program.

```
#include "vmlinux.h"
#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_core_read.h>

char LICENSE[] SEC("license") = "GPL";

SEC("tp/syscalls/sys_enter_execve")
int handle_tp(void *ctx)
{
 struct task_struct *task;
 task = (struct task_struct*)bpf_get_current_task();
 struct path p;
 p = BPF_CORE_READ(task, mm, exe_file, f_path);
 char path_exe[256];
 bpf_d_path(&p, path_exe, sizeof(path_exe));
 bpf_printk("TASK: %s", path_exe);

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am very grateful for your answer. This may be possible for higher versions, but my kernel version is 4.19. Do you have any other ideas if I don't upgrade the kernel version

Comment: This solution is not feasible on even higher versions where bpf_d_path() is supported, because bpf_d_path() is not allowed from tracepoints or raw tracepoints yet! Check the allowed syscalls here:https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/a92b7d26c743b9dc06d520f863d624e94978a1d9/kernel/trace/bpf_trace.c#L930